# Add data from html form to dynamodb using lambda / python or node.js

Tags: java, python, node.js, amazon-web-services

I have this simple form:

```html
  <form action="" method="POST" >
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have dynamodb already setup on aws and would like to have your help to get a node.js or python script in lambda to add data from the form to dynamodb when click on submit

Comment: the form is:

"<form action="" method="POST" >
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>"